# Question on sets. Intersection of 2 subsets.

Tags: probability

This is from a probability question dealing with sets and subsets

$S=\{1-45\}$, $A=${multiples of 2 (22)} , $B=${multiples of 3 (15)}. How to find the intersection of these two sets? Essentially all numbers between 1-45 that are multiples of both 2 and 3.

Hope someone can help. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried anything?  Simply listing the numbers is easy enough.

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format your posts.

Comment: Chase, thanks mate. Will keep that in mind for the next one.

Comment: Thank you Lulu. Yes I did list them in the end but I wanted a formula or method for larger sets. I'm sure you would agree it would not be practical to be listing multiples in a set as large as 1000.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first is $6$, the last is $42$ and if $n$ is a number of needed numbers then we obtain:
$$6+(n-1)6=42$$ or
$n=7$ and we have the answer:
$$\{6,12,18,24,30,36,42\}$$

Comment: Thanks MIchael! The help is much appreciated. I assume you are using the form Tn=a+(n-1)d. Brilliant solution.

Comment: @Shan Govind You are welcome!

Answer (score 0):

\begin{eqnarray*}
S &=& \{ 1,2, \cdots , 45 \} \\
A&=& \{ x \in S \mid x \text{ is a multiple of $2$ } \} \\
B&=& \{ x \in S \mid x \text{ is a multiple of $3$ } \} \\
A \cap B &=& \{ x \in S \mid x \text{ is a multiple of $6$ } \} \\
&=& \{ 6,12, \cdots ,42  \} \\
\end{eqnarray*}
$ \mid A \cap B \mid = \color{blue}{7}$.

Comment: Thank you Donald. At a glance I can see the logic behind this. I will give it a bit more of a try before voting up tomorrow. Thank you again.